# Tkinter- issue closing a window

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am running into an issue when trying to close tkinter in jupyter notebook. I am trying to create a button that quits the program when the user clicks on the button "quit."

The following is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
global folder_path
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            label = tk.Label(self, text="BTC Price Difference", font=LARGE_FONT)
            label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            closebutton=tk.Button(self,text="Quit",command=self.close_all)
            closebutton.pack()

    def close_all(self):
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

I am unusure what the issue could be. Should it not be in `__init__`? 
Also,  could it be I shouldn't be creating my first window in `__init__`? 
When I run the code, the screen freezes and nothing runs.

Comment: What is the issue that needs to be solved? What does this code do that is different than what you expect?

Comment: I explained I want the program to close when the user clicks "quit" but right now the screen just freezes when clicking quit.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. When I click the Quit button, the program quits.

Comment: My screen freezes, and it is unable to quit, could it be an issue when running in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, running in jupyter notebook is an important detail that you should include in the question.

Comment: @Monica: Relevant [issues-with-tk-in-ipython-jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520108/issues-with-tk-in-ipython-jupyter), unfortunatly without answer.

Comment: Aright, thanks! I will run it in another application.

Comment: Try `closebutton=tk.Button(self,text="Quit",command=controller.destroy)`.

Comment: @acw1668, thanks that works!